# People type column autofill from email column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have an email column in the list , i want to create another column with the type of People by looking up in the email column so that i can filter the filter the list by the Current user filter.

Answer (score 0):

Create an event receiver on your list. On itemadding and itemupdating (or -ed) get the field value of the email column. You can then ensure the SPUser object with the emailadress. Use this SPUser object to update the People column

Comment: Can it be done to an existing list without the need to update or add ?

Comment: Well you can execute similar code while looping through each item in the list. Another option is using workflows in SP Designer but i am not sure if you can achieve this behaviour using that.